# React Native: Cache Image, Video, all type of documents (.pdf, .xls, ..) in iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, caching

I have a scenario to cache all types of user files (Image, Video, all word documents, pdf, etc) in react native application. Currently, I am using react-native-fast-image for image cache which is actually working the best.

But I need any popular library/approach which can handle all types of mentioned files.

Currently, I am using FastImage component as given below

```
      <FastImage source={{uri: source}}
        resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.cover}
        style={{...style}}
        onLoad={(e) => {
          this.setState({imageLoaded: true})
        }}
      />
```